# Return all existing values as JSON

Tags: javascript, json, angular, typescript

The following code will output all the keys and values form my form:

```js
this.primaryFormGroup.valueChanges.subscribe(inputFields => {
  console.log(inputFields);
}
```

It will output all the values, even if they are empty but that is not what I want.

```
Object.entries(inputFields).filter(([key, value]) => value)
```

This will output only the values, which are not empty. So far, everything is good.

**My problem**

The output is always an array but what I want is JSON.

I have tried it with `JSON.stringify(Object.entries(inputFields).filter(([key, value]) => value));` and this is how the output will be:

> [["title","Hello"],["description","I am a
>   text"],["tech",["javaScript","CSS"]]]

In my case the value of the key `tech` should be an array, since it is already defined as array but everything else should be JSON.

How can I do this?

Comment: _"what I want is JSON"_ + _"key `tech` should be an array...but everything else should be JSON"_?

Comment: @Andreas yes! This is what I want: `{ "title": "Hello", "description": "I am a text", "tech": ["JavaScript", "CSS"] }`

Comment: Could you please provide a sample about how your form looks like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To filter out all null or empty values you could try the following:

```
this.primaryFormGroup.valueChanges.subscribe(inputFields => {
  const clean = Object.keys(inputFields).filter(k => !!inputFields [k]).reduce((acc, curr) => {
          acc[curr] = inputFields[curr];
          return acc;
  }, {});
}
```

Note:
This solution will not work with deep forms.

Answer (score 0):

```js
// assuming initial values of all form controls is undefined.
const formValues = this.primaryFormGroup.value;

const formValuesWithNoundefinedKeys = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(formValues));

// formValuesWithNoUndefinedKeys won't contain any keys with undefined values
```

If you need to remove null values as well, you can provide a [REPLACER](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) function to JSON.stringify function.

Example snippet below:

```js
const obj = {a: undefined, b:1}

const objWithNoUndefinedValues = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj))
// objWithNoUndefinedValues => {b: 1}

console.log(objWithNoUndefinedValues)
```